# I want my character to do something as long as I'm holding a button, then go back to normal once I let go of the button

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating my first game. I'm working with Python and PyGame. So far everything has been going great, but I've ran into a problem that I can't seem to solve:

I want my character to do a certain movement as long as I'm pressing a button.
Normally when you want to make your character move, I would do

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
```

With this, the character does something when you press space, but it only does it once if you HOLD space.
I thought I'd do this

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

    while event.key = pygame.K_SPACE
```

But when I run this and press space, the program blocks, and I get the 'program isn't reacting' thing.

So, one last time. I want my character to do something when I hold space, and when I let go I want it to go back to how it was. 
For example: My character is walking by default. When I hold space I want it to crawl for as long as I hold space. And then finally I want it to go back to normal walking once I let go of space.

Is this possible?

Comment: maybe you just add a ```time.sleep(0.1)``` in the while-loop

Comment: Don't use a `while`. Set a flag if space is reported in a KEYDOWN event, and reset it when space is released. Then in your main loop check that flag.

Comment: Can't you just listen for the `KEYUP` event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a state (`spacePressed`) if <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed when the `KEYDOWN` event is received. Reset the state and rest the position of the character if the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is released and `KEYUP` is received. Move the character dependent on `spacePressed` in the main application loop e.g.:

```py
spacePressed = False
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                spacePressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                spacePressed = False
                # reset character
                # [...]

    if spacePressed:
        # move character
        # [...]
```

---

Another option is to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to get the pressed keys in the main application loop and reset the position of the character if the `KEYUP` event is received:

```py
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                # reset character
                # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        # move character
        # [...]
```